# Excel formula - lookup a cell and return a different value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some raw data. Where I want to look up data from a row, see if it appears again in the whole sheet, and where it appears again it will return a value from the same row (not the same cell).

E.g because B7 matches, I want it to reference 3 bits of data in E,F,G 2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So you have one sheet, and you want to fill in missing cells in columns E, F and G? For example, you want row 7 to look like row 2 (for cols E, F, G)?

Comment: so basically for the end result, I want to be able to pivot the sheet and show that the same item that was shorted from 'HAM2' were found in 'FOR1' if that helps. The data needs to be pivoted as it will be quite substantial

Comment: Oh, i see. Your data are columns A through D, and you want to write out to columns E, F and G. Is that correct?

Comment: have also attached a pivot in the current format. This is pivoted by item reference which shows the place reference. I almost need to turning around to show place reference by item, however by switching it around in the table it doesnt work. perhaps some way of concatinating the place reference would be useful

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 0):

I can delete this answer if this doesn't resolve your issue. I don't understand how complex your data are, so this may not work.

I sorted the data by Item, then Short (descending).

Then here are the formulas for cell E2, F2 and G2:

```
    E2: =IF(AND($B2=$B1,$C2=0),A1,"")

    F2: =IF(AND($B2=$B1,$C2=0),C1,"")

    G2: =IF(AND($B2=$B1,$C2=0),D1,"")
```

Drag 'em down.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this has definitely brought me closer to the answer, however as feared the data is quite complex for reasons I have attached (sometimes the item number quantity is not collated as shown) and also removed the formula if C2=0 as sometimes this is not always the case. Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. Hope someone else has some ideas.